# #id property definition inside #id

Tags: html, css, visibility

Is there any way to define an id property inside a #id? Like:

```
#box1:hover{

    #box2{visibility:visible;}
}
```

Comment: _Why_ would you want to do this? What is your intention? What you want to do is not correct in CSS. Again: what's the intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
#box1:hover #box2 {visibility:visible}
```

Basically it means: I want to make the child visible "hovering" the parent... or: I want to make visible the inner element hovering the outer one.

Did i guess correctly?

Comment: Thank you sir! Yes you did.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you mean is that you want to select the `#box2` within `#box1` when the latter is being hovered.

You can use the [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) for that:

```css
#box1:hover #box2 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about nesting selectors. This is possible with a preproccessor such as SASS, and it's exactly as you described.

```
#box1:hover {
  #box2 {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Otherwise, without SASS, you would have to use the descendant selector

```
#box1:hover #box2 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```